# How to write factorials in objective c

Tags: objective-c, loops, factorial

I have been reading a programming book and it wants me to write a program listing a table of the first 10 factorial numbers. I have been trying for the past 45 minutes, but can't come up with a solution. Please Help! I'm pretty sure the program involves using loops.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to calculate the factorial is with a recursive function or a simple loop as shown below.  I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to list the information in a table as there are lots of ways to skin that cat.

Header File Function Declaration:

```
-(int)factorialRecursive:(int)operand;
-(int)factorialLoop:(int)operand;
```

Implementation File Function Declaration:

```
-(int)factorialRecursive:(int)operand
{
    if( operand == 1 || operand == 0) {
        return(1);
    } else if( operand < 0 ) {
        return(-1);
    }

    return( operand * [self factorialRecursive:operand-1] );
}

-(int)factorialLoop:(int)operand
{

    if( operand == 1 || operand == 0) {
        return(1);
    } else if( operand < 0 ) {
        return(-1);
    }

    int factorial = 1;
    for(int i = operand; i > 1; i-- ) {
        factorial *= i;
    }

    return( factorial );

}
```

Sample Call:

```
int factNumber = 10;
NSLog(@"%d! = %d",factNumber,[self factorialRecursive:factNumber]);
NSLog(@"%d! = %d",factNumber,[self factorialLoop:factNumber]);
```

Comment: Recursion? Why? Use a simple loop please.

Comment: No argument there.  Iterative loops are faster when n is large because the overhead in a loop is much less than a recursive method calls.  I simply tried to answer his question with the little information he provided in terms of requirements. ;)  I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The OP did mention loops, not recursion.

Comment: D'oh, missed that. Sorry.  I have angered the SO gods.  Although I did see you edited his post, so hard to say that I remember exactly what he wrote in his original post. ;P

Comment: Feel free to improve upon what I wrote.  I was simply trying to help a programming newbie get started with something in hopes that he will have the insight to ask those questions as well.  I never claimed to be an expert myself and am well aware that there are limitations when n gets to be very large.

Comment: @SlyRaskal The only edit I made to the OP's post was to remove an irrelevant tag.

Comment: @rmaddy, I'm just pulling your chain.  I understand you are being constructive and supportive. No ill feelings here. :)

Comment: @SlyRaskal None intended and none taken. We're all good. :)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not that advanced yet to understand the program, so is there a way that you could simplify that?